# Passing a new instance of a Type through a Generic Method

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, types

I have a series of very similar methods:

```
    private static DocumentBody GetPdfBodyObject(int sectionId)
    {
        DocumentBody db = new DocumentBody();
        // Add some stuff to Db
        return db;
    }

    private static DocumentHeader GetPdfHeaderObject(int sectionId)
    {
        DocumentHeader dh = new DocumentHeader();
        // Add some stuff to DH - similar to above
        return dh;
    }
```

And so on...

As you can see the difference between these two examples is based around the Type that is being instantiated & returned.

So instantly I thought to use a Generic Method to reduce the code duplication... I just cant seem to figure out which way is the 'best practice' and can I get what I need without using reflection?

I haven't used Generic Methods much at all so any advice is welcome.

Comment: Seems like you could use a factory, assuming all your types inherit from a common base-class or implement a common interface. But I´m not sure what a header and a body have in common...

Comment: You could actually try to make the method generic and use Activator class (see: https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/dotnet/api/system.activator.createinstance?view=netframework-4.7.2 ) to create appropriate instance. Though, factory sounds like a better idea to me

Comment: How similar are the sections implied by the comments above? Do `DocumentBody` and `DocumentHeader` share any common interfaces/base classes?

Comment: They don't currently but they will shortly. This sequence of code strictly only updates the common properties so will get that done and test out a few of these ideas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As for me, interfaces are good:

```
private interface IDocumentPart
{
}

private class DocumentHeader : IDocumentPart
{
}

private class DocumentBody : IDocumentPart
{
}

private static T GetPdfPart<T>(int sectionId) where T : IDocumentPart, new()
{
       var doc = new T();
       return doc;
}
```

Of course, you can define some properties and methods common for all your classes in an interface.

Comment: Perfect! I had read about this Method functionality a while ago and wondered when I might ever put it into practice - it just dropped off my radar! Many thanks, works a treat!

Answer (score 4):

The best practice here would be to refactor static methods to factory methods or use [builder pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) if it's a bigger object you're building (which it appears to be the case). The use of generic methods would be limited here to parameterless constructors - whenever the constructor would take parameters, you'd need to use the Activator, which is reflection and you generally do not want such code. Having said that: the two methods you gave construct objects using parameterless constructors, so you can refactor both to:

```
private static TT GetPdfObjectPart<TT>(int sectionId) where TT : class, new()
{
    TT dh = new TT();
    // Add some stuff to DH - similar to above
    return dh;
}
```

Also note, that as  @dymanoid pointed out - in this case you can only use what is the part of the contract (the *where* clause) - so you'd need to implement 
some 'generic' interface to all constructed types - and you'd be limited to methods from the interface. It really looks like you're in classical situation to use the builder pattern.

Comment: "Some stuff" can be in this case only `dh.GetHashCode()` and `dh.ToString()`, because there's no information at compile time what type the object is of.

Comment: Therefore, builder pattern would be my choice. But thanks for pointing that out, I will ammend my answer